# Dismiss ChildView From ParentViewController

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uiviewcontroller

I have a parent view that opens a child view like so:

```
ChildViewController *child = [[ChildViewController alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];
[self presentModalViewController:child animated:YES];
```

Which works perfectly fine. I need to dismiss the child view from the parent view but when I do that, nothing happens. Is it because the parent view stops all of its processes when I open the child view? Or is it my code: `[child dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];` ? Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

dismissModalViewControllerAnimated: has to be called on the same object that presentModalViewController:animated: was called on.

In your example, it would need to be `[self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];`

If you were dismissing from inside the controller being displayed modally, it would be as @James Bedford described `[[self parentViewController] dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];`

Comment: Thanks for clearing that up for me. I thought you were supposed to call self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated from the child view but I guess not.

Answer (score 1):

Where are you calling `[child dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];`? Is this line of code ever being reached?

You could add a target/action to one of your *UIControls* within your *ChildViewController* class which uses the inherited *parentViewController* property to dismiss itself as follows:

`[[self parentViewController] dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];`

Comment: The line of code is being called from the parent, but the child does not close. I put a NSLog there and it shows up in the console so I know it is being called from the parent.